# Unable to get the guid of splistitem with SPQuery

Tags: splistitem

I am trying to get some information from a SPListItem by the following code:

```
 SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[listName];
 SPView spview = list.Views["All Items"];
 SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
 query.Query = string.Concat(
                         "<Where><Eq>",
                                         "<FieldRef Name='ID'/>",
                                         "<Value Type='Integer'>" + the_Item_ID + "</Value>",
                                      "</Eq></Where>");

            foreach (string viewField in spview.ViewFields)
            {
                query.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name='" + viewField + "' />";
            }
            query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";
            query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;

SPListItemCollection items list.GetItems(query);
SPListItem item = items[0];
//string title  = Convert.ToString(item["Title"]);// <-Fail, i don't know why
string title = Convert.ToString(item["LinkTitle"]); //<- pass

Guid id = item.UniqueId;//Fail, i don't know why
```

Can anyone tell me how to get the uniqueid of splistitem?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want yo retrieve an item from its ID (as your current CAML query suggests), you can simply use the call to `list.GetItemById`. That way your `SPListItem` will ne full populated, and I'm sure `UniqueId` will ne OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[listName]; 
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = string.Concat(
                 "<Where><Eq>",
                                 "<FieldRef Name='ID'/>",
                                 "<Value Type='Integer'>" + the_Item_ID + "</Value>",
                              "</Eq></Where>");

//specify the field names that you want to use later on in the code
query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='LinkTitle' /><FieldRef Name='UniqueId' /><FieldRef Name='ID' />";

query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";
query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;

SPListItemCollection items list.GetItems(query);
SPListItem item = items[0];
string title  = Convert.ToString(item["Title"]);
string linkTitle = Convert.ToString(item["LinkTitle"]); 

Guid id = item.UniqueId;
```

By default, the `All Items` view has the `LinkTitle` field and not `Title` field. So, your code failed as it got the view fields from the all items view. 
To get the view fields that you want, you need to specify them as in the above code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove this line

```
    query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
```

This option prohibits access to columns like UniqueId.